# LocalReport Receipt Printing

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am printing a 3 inch receipt using a LocalReport with code from "[Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)"

Some printers require the DeviceInfo PageWidth to be 8.5in to work correctly and some require 3.0in.  Its appears that the report is being stretched to fill a wrong sized page.  I have tried to adjust both the Report Paper Size and the Printer Paper size but can't seem to get the right combination.

Has anybody experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  You need to account for the printer dpi.

Get the Printer Default Page Settings:

```
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        ps.PrinterName = printerName;
        this.defaultPageSettings = ps.DefaultPageSettings;
```

The Build the DeviceInfo Xml with that info:

```
    private string BuildDeviceInfo()
    {
        StringBuilder returnValue;
        System.Xml.XmlWriter writer;

        returnValue = new StringBuilder(1024);
        writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(returnValue);

        writer.WriteStartElement("DeviceInfo");
        writer.WriteElementString("OutputFormat", "EMF");

        if (defaultPageSettings != null)
        {
            // DPI will keep the output from scaling in weird ways
            writer.WriteElementString("PrintDpiX", defaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X.ToString());
            writer.WriteElementString("PrintDpiY", defaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y.ToString());

            writer.WriteElementString("PageWidth", (defaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width / 100m).ToString("F2") + "in");
            writer.WriteElementString("PageHeight", (defaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height / 100m).ToString("F2") + "in");
       }
        writer.Close();

        return returnValue.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I'm printing from a WPF app to a STAR TSP100 receipt printer.  When I set the margins & page size myself it came out huge, but when I calculated the minimum margins and page size as well as set the dpi from default printer settings the receipts printed correctly.

I used this to figure out the minimum margins: (H/T http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/135864-printing-with-minimum-margins-specified-by-the-printer/)

```
Dim minimumMarginLeft, minimumMarginRight, minimumMarginTop,
 minimumMarginBottom As Single

minimumMarginLeft = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Left

minimumMarginRight = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - _
                                  PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Right

minimumMarginTop = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Top

minimumMarginBottom =  PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - _
                                      PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Bottom


-I figured this out. You need to account for the printer dpi.

-Get the Printer Default Page Settings:

        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        ps.PrinterName = printerName;
        this.defaultPageSettings = ps.DefaultPageSettings; The Build the DeviceInfo Xml with that info:

    private string BuildDeviceInfo()
    {
        StringBuilder returnValue;
        System.Xml.XmlWriter writer;

        returnValue = new StringBuilder(1024);
        writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(returnValue);

        writer.WriteStartElement("DeviceInfo");
        writer.WriteElementString("OutputFormat", "EMF");

        if (defaultPageSettings != null)
        {
            // DPI will keep the output from scaling in weird ways
            writer.WriteElementString("PrintDpiX", defaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X.ToString());
            writer.WriteElementString("PrintDpiY", defaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y.ToString());

            writer.WriteElementString("PageWidth", (defaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width / 100m).ToString("F2") + "in");
            writer.WriteElementString("PageHeight", (defaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height / 100m).ToString("F2") + "in");
       }
        writer.Close();

        return returnValue.ToString();
    }
```